# Android: How to do create custom EditText with a clickable arrow on the right

Tags: android

I would like to have an EditText with one modification: on the right  but still inside the EditText there should an arrow pointing downwards that I can set `OnClickListener` to so that when the user clicks on the arrow it displays a menu.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this by putting `EditText` and a Button into `RelativeLayout`, the Button (which has `custom background drawable`) is overlapping the `EditBox`.

When user clicks on it, the `EditBox` doesn't receive the `click event`.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like this ?

[image]

[see image](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/wDsF1EN3kvyoZELsvRBixQ?feat=directlink)

Add the arrow by setting the drawable right attribute

```
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/right"
```

to your `EditText`. Then you would need to set an `OnTouchListener` to get the events.

Comment: I did not try this (already found a solution) but I think that click on the arrow would also open keyboard. But thanks anyway...

Comment: Not sure about how to set the listener to handle the events only when the user touches the image (not the whole EditText)...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a combo box.  If you look at the "[Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)" section of the Dev Guide, they mention combo box briefly, but give details on how to build any custom component.