# Android: Adding Custom online suggestions to Search Dialog

Tags: android

Please provide me some pointer to implement custom suggestion that re-fetched from online web services.

As soon a user starts typing the character in the search bar I want to send a online query to fetch data and display in suggestion list.

Comment: looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264589/search-suggestions-from-network-resource-into-quick-search-box

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have got the idea how to implement these but still due to some configuration i am not able to hit the query() method in my ContentProvider

Comment: hello androidexp, please help me for how to use online query fire when type in search box.